# accessing instance variables in other controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, accessor

I have 2 controllers `coordinates` and `photoexifdatas` and I would like to access one of the instance variables in `photoexifdatas` inside `coordinates`.Here's my code:

**photoexifdatas_controller.rb**

```
class PhotoexifdatasController < ApplicationController
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
attr_accessor :photoexifdatas
attr_accessor :pc

def index
    @pc = Photoexifdata.find(1);
$pcd = Photoexifdata.find(1).lattitude;
    @photoexifdatas = Photoexifdata.all
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json {render json: @photoexifdatas }

end
end

def create

@lattitude = params[:lattitude]
@longitude = params[:longitude]
p = Photoexifdata.new 
p.lattitude =  @lattitude
p.longitude =  @longitude
p.save
redirect_to '/photoexifdatas'
end
end
```

When I do a `<%= puts PhotoexifdatasController.pc %>` in **views/coordinates/index.html.erb** 
It doesnt print up.What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `<%= puts PhotoexifdatasController.pc %>` in your **views/coordinates/index.html.erb**, what happens is that you try to access the pc method of the `PhotoexifdatasController` class (you're not actually calling it on an instance of the `PhotoexifdatasController` class).

It's not a good idea when you want to access an instance variable of one controller from another controller. I would recommend that if you want to access a `Photoexifdata` model within the `CoordinatesController`, just do a normal query like `Photoexifdata.find(1)` and assign it on an instance variable within the `CoordinatesController`. You can always access any model instance within the `CoordinatesController`.